# How to know if javascript is suppose to be in the <head> or at bottom of the html?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `<head>` full of .css, .js and metadata. But there is just one script that will not run properly if it is put in the `<head>` of the html. It will only work if it is at the end of the file.

What I would like to know is, if there are any documentation regarding this or a special type of rules I should follow as a beginner web designer.

```
<html>
<head>
 <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="css/style2.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="js/script.js"></script>
 <script src="js/scipt2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<----------HTML---------->
</body>
 <script src="js/secret.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: putting your code at the end of the document just ensures that the dom has loaded before the script. i havent' put a script in the head of a document in about 10 years. there are very, very few instances when a script really needs to be in the head.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The modern way to solve this issue is to use the `defer` attribute on the script tag. Put all your tags in the `<head>`

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#Attributes):

> This Boolean attribute is set to indicate to a browser that the script
>   is meant to be executed after the document has been parsed, but before
>   firing DOMContentLoaded.

So this:

```
<script src="js/secret.js"></script>
```

becomes this:

```
<script defer src="js/secret.js"></script>
```

But the tag now goes into the `<head>`.